# Хранение файла НЕ на сервере

Tags: javascript, python

Подскажите, возможно ли хранить файлы в памяти устройства, но не на сервере. Если есть - подскажите где почитать, как задать вопрос гуглу

Приложение написано на django 4.2
фронт к нему на html/css/js и немного jQuery

Comment: Что ты понимаешь под фразой "память устройства"?

Comment: @ksa Возможно он имеет ввиду: как хранить файлы на стороне клиента. Думаю ему нужно [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T, да все верно. Спасибо за ответ. В связи с сложностью реализации решили отказаться от данной задумки. Хранения файлов на сервере вполне достаточно, судя по расчетом затрат на жд